Are there any studies that have examined the narcissism levels of scientists in philosophy, mathematics and physics?
I would be interested in studies on this topic. I think that obviously false theories are defended for too long due to high narcissism scores.

Have you researched the question before? Can you share what you found?

I was looking for something but unfortunately I didn't find anything concrete. That's why I asked here. :) @Ooker

Well, your last comment is provocative and dismissive at the same time. I agree with your conclusion that there seem not to be any NPI or studies of subclinical narcissism in the fields you specify - my searches found nothing. However, there may be correlational studies related to gender prevalence and personality characteristics in those fields, but they seem to neglect the dark triad (/tetrad) - for reasons that for effectiveness in the fields it may not be considered relevant. Why not do a study on it yourself if you can get funding?

@Cricket Maybe I expressed myself a bit dismissively, but that was not my intention. I am writing a paper on epistemology and would like a paper to briefly address this. I am not a researcher in psychology.

Not an answer, but one thing worth noting is that scientists in these fields start out as students in these fields, and students in these fields are quite often convenience samples for human studies. Thus, even if there are no studies of narcissism in scientists, there are very likely to be studies of narcissism in students. Additionally, there is a fair bit of evidence that such samples are valid because they are representative of the general population, so my prior is that narcissism levels amongst students are roughly the same as the general population.
